# Conflict between integration sign and strict implication sign

Tags: symbols

I am trying to use the strict implication sign using pxfonts/txfonts, but it destroys my use of the integration sign.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{scrartcl}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\makeatletter\let\TTTemp\cap\makeatother
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{teubner}
\makeatletter\let\cap\TTTemp\makeatother
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{lgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\begin{document}
$\strictif$



$\int$ - Missing integration symbol
\end{document}
```

Comment: that's not a very minimal MWE:-)

Comment: That is true. I may minimalize it more, but that will take some caution.

Comment: It's much better if the questioner does that work before posting rather than everyone trying to help having to duplicate that effort

Comment: Thanks. I assumed this would be effortless to many. I now see that I may also learn some on how the things work by trying to minimalize maximally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You load a ton of packages I suspect you will need all of it. But the problem of `\int` is not caused by `pxfonts` but `MnSymbol`, move it last or get rid of it completely.

With `MnSymbol` loaded last:

[image]

With `MnSymbol` removed:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use the newer `newpxmath` package the issue seems to go

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
%\usepackage{pxfonts}
\let\mid\relax\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\begin{document}
$\strictif$

$\int$ - Missing integration symbol
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not work for me.